# Android listener imageview effectively drawn

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm creating an android app to people draw names out of a set (raffle).

I want to create an animation where after pressing the button the app goes randomly between the names and show them (with photos) for a short time them replace for a next one and on and on (like a raffling effect)

The effect is working pretty fine for the NAMES, the problem i got is with the images

what i do is:

```
 final View drawingView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.winner_inspect_layout, null);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(drawingView).show();

        final AppCompatImageView ivPhoto = drawingView.findViewById(R.id.winnerPhoto);
        final AppCompatTextView txName = drawingView.findViewById(R.id.winnerName);
        final AppCompatTextView txComment = drawingView.findViewById(R.id.winnerComment);


        ivPhoto.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new Puzzler(ivPhoto, txName, txComment, validTickets, 6000));
        ivPhoto.forceLayout();
```

and the `Puzzler` does:

```
 @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Comment ticket = this.tickets.poll();
            this.txName.setText(ticket.getId() + "");
            this.txComment.setText(ticket.getText());

            Picasso.get().load(ticket.getProfilePhotoUrl()).fit().into(this.ivPhoto);

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.startTime > this.maxTime || this.tickets.isEmpty()) {
                ivPhoto.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                annouceWinner(ivPhoto);
            }

        }
```

So i do watch global layout on the imageview hopping that the method will be called after the whole image has been made visible.... but what actually happens is the method is called before the image is visible... so it is possible to see the names switching each other, but the images is just possible to see 1 or 2 in the whole process...

i made a very very short video showing the effect (plase take 15 seconds to watch)
https://youtu.be/nxykGdBwIeM

how can i listen the event of the image being really displayed to the user? the actual effect with the names is what i desire, but as is possible to watch most of the photos are switched before being visible

Comment: I believe Picasso's load.into is executed asynchronously. Don't remember how to fetch it synchronously outside of calling .get() instead of into (can you call both? No idea), but it'll make the "raffle" super slow anyway as you will be loading those images one by one. Instead you should load images in advance (figure out how to do it adynchronously, i suggest using picasso's .fetch(callback) and load them from memory during raffle.

Comment: I am fetching the images during the video ad... Most of them should already be in cache... The point is doesn't matter if 'into' is sync or async my point is that if I could call it ONLY when the image is already visible I would get a glance of the image for a least few milliseconds....  But on global layout is being called for another reason other than image is shown...

Comment: Well i dont see them being fetched all I see is you calling Picasso.load(url) and even if url points at locally stored pictures, it still needs to load them into a bitmap and resize and all that. It takes a lot more times than fetching text that is already in ram. Also view.setText is a blocking operation while Picasso.load.into is not. It starts loading in another thread and continues execution, which means it may start next iteration before finishing loading first image. But then i may be comoletely wrong but i dont think i am. Try doing a `Bitmap b = Picasso.load.get; view.serBitmap(b);`

Comment: Oh, i think i get whst you mean on second read. Idk whst to do about it though.